# Makung requests to shopify apis in shopify liquid file

Tags: shopify, rest, shopify-template, shopify-api

How can I make request to shopify api in shopify liquid file? As the shop name and store's live website have diff urls, it treats it as cross-originated request and require me to provide auth tokens and give net error 401. So how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific about which API you want to access. Storefront API is available to you with a token. Admin is not. If you want access to the Admin APIs you must do it via an App Proxy.